# C# How to set Generic type with abstract method

Tags: c#, generics

I have an abstruct class with abstract method, the method param is generic.

this is the param type declaration:

```
public class StepHandlerWrapper<T> where T : BaseStepDataModel{...}
```

this is the parent abstract:
**this is actually the problem, I want the StepHandlerWrapper generic type to be dynamic on each implementaion**:

```
public abstract class BaseStepHandler{
  protected abstract HandlerResult Handle(StepHandlerWrapper<???????????????> );
}
```

these are 2 implementations **Note the generic type on each one (different)**:

```
     public  class LoginHandler : BaseStepHandler {
          protected override HandlerResult Handle(StepHandlerWrapper<LoginStepOneDataModel> wrapper){...}
}



  public class RegularDemoAccountHandler : BaseStepHandler{
           protected override HandlerResult Handle(StepHandlerWrapper<RegularDemoAccountStepOneDataModel> wrapper){...}
  }
```

how do I make each implementation of the abstract method to be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `BaseStepHandler` generic as well:

```
public abstract class BaseStepHandler<T> where T : BaseStepDataModel { 
    protected abstract HandlerResult Handle(StepHandlerWrapper<T> wrapper); 
} 

public class LoginHandler : BaseStepHandler<LoginStepOneDataModel> {
    protected override HandlerResult Handle(StepHandlerWrapper<LoginStepOneDataModel> wrapper) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 implementations are both DataModels, so why not make that an abstract class where both implementations derive from:

```
abstract DataModel {

}

class LoginStepOneDataModel : DataModel {

}

class RegularDemoAccountStepOneDataModel : DataModel {

}

public abstract class BaseStepHandler{
  protected abstract HandlerResult Handle(StepHandlerWrapper<DataModel>);
}
```

Comment: DataModel is actually just a "Marker". I want to have different type on each implementation (this will help me to avoid casting).